# WebBrowser close file download dialog box

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am downloading files with  windows.Forms.WebBrowser c#,after i run InvokeScript ,and get my file i use  Application.DoEvents to move forward to my  next file ,but the download dialog stays opened and i get stuck on  Application.DoEvents, and cant do nothing.

How can i cancel or close this download dialog?

My code:

```
     HtmlElement head = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("btnExcelExport");
     HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
     IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
     element.text = "function DownloadFile() {$('#btnExcelExport').click()}";
     head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
     webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("DownloadFile");

     HtmlElementCollection iFrames =     webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("iframe");
                for (int i = 0; i < iFrames.Count; i++)
                {
                    string src = iFrames[i].GetAttribute("src");
                    if (src.Contains("Export"))
                    {
                        txt_url.Text = "https://test.com" + src;

                        string cooki = webBrowser.Document.Cookie;
                        int response = URLDownloadToFile(0, "https://test.com" + src, @"C:\temp\Test.txt", 0, 0);

                    }

                }
                Application.DoEvents();
//....got to next file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I down know that was wrong with my question, and why i  get down-rate , but any way i found this solution.

You need yo use   Navigating event and there check is you in the download url  use cancel download "e.Cancel = true"

```
private void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender,WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Url.ToString().Contains("Download"))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            }
```